# Cannot validate the new form

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-validate

I have a html page with a button and a div (newFormDiv), when user click the button, it will call up an ajax function to write a new form (commentForm) in div newFormDiv. in the new form, user will input something in artPlaceName, the length must be bigger than 1.
I tried to use jquery validataion to do it, but never successful.

any help will be appreciated.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
                     "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
   <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
   <script src="formajax.js"></script>
   <script src="formvalidation.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<form>
<button>Create New Form</button>
</form>
<div id="newFormDiv">
<p>This is new form area.</p>
</div>
<script>
$( "button" ).click(function () {
testFutureForm();
return false;
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

futureForm.php

```
<?php
echo '

  <form id="commentForm" method="get" action="">
  <fieldset>
    <p>
      <input id="artPlaceName" name="name" size="25"/>
    </p>
    <p>
      <input id="placeSubmit" class="submit" type="button" value="Submit"/>
    </p>
  </fieldset>
  </form>
';
?>
```

formajax.js

```
function testFutureForm()
{
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 )
    {
    document.getElementById("newFormDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","futureForm.php",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

formvalidation.js

```
$( "form" ).on( "click", "#placeSubmit",
    function(){$("#commentForm").validate(
               {
                   rules:
                   {
                       artPlaceName:
                           {
                               required: true,
                               minlength: 2
                           }

                   },
       messages:
                   {
           artPlaceName:
                       {
                           required: "<li>Please enter a name.</li>",
                           minlength: "<li>Your name is not long enough.</li>"
                       }
                   }
               }
         );}
         );
```

Comment: _"...but never successful"_ ~  You're going to have to do a much better job describing the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With better code formatting, your syntax error becomes obvious...

```
    $("#commentForm").validate({
       debug: true; // <-- semicolon not allowed here, should be a comma
       rules: {
            artPlaceName: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 2
            }
        },          // <-- see how a comma separates each key/value pair
        messages: {
            artPlaceName: {
                required: "<li>Please enter a name.</li>",
                minlength: "<li>Your name is not long enough.</li>"
            }
        }
    });
```

The semicolon `;` after `debug: true` would be breaking the whole thing.  Change it to a comma, `,`.  Please note that `debug: true` will also block the submit event of the form.

Also, get rid of your `click` handler...

```
$( "form" ).on( "click", "#placeSubmit",
```

It's not needed.  The jQuery Validate plugin automatically captures the click event of the submit button.

Since your form is dynamically created, call `.validate()` immediately after the form is loaded onto the page.  Put it just after the code that loads the new form.

---

You do not need to declare your rules in two places.  Since you've already declared `required` and `minlength` rules within your `.validate()` call above, you do not need the inline attributes.

```
<input id="artPlaceName" name="name" size="25" class="required" minlength="2" />
```

Can simply be written like this...

```
<input id="artPlaceName" name="name" size="25" />
```

Comment: Thanks, Sparky

I tried your solution, it still doesn't work. Based on your suggestion, I have modified code above.

The problem in my case is the commentForm doesn't exist before formvalidation.js loaded. When I tried open index.html in firefox, I cannot even see formvalidation.js is loaded. then I pressed Ctrl + Shft + R, I can see it is loaded, but still doesn't work.
As I researched, .on seems to be the solution, but I spent 2 days on it, still can not make it.

Comment: @user2920375,  you can't use `.on()` because you cannot delegate `.validate()`. As I explained in my answer, you must call `.validate()` immediately AFTER you load the form's HTML.

Comment: Thank you so much. Finally make it works with your help in this thread and below url you mentioned in another thread. http://jsfiddle.net/dUmfK/